# iphone development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser

I am still new in objective-c. I want to create an application on iphone in which I take a data from XML using NSXMLParser. so when I start the application It will read the XML and data are coming from that,but in between in running appliaction if the XML is updated then how can my application know about it and get that refreash data?Please help me on that.

Comment: Where is the XML coming from? File system, or network?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your application would benefit from using the new [Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/sdk/apns.html) API in the 3.0 OS.

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic. Either your app has to poll or you can keep a connection open and send an indication from the server when the data changes.

Apple push notification may or may not do that but either way, the simplest way from where you are now is to poll your server.

Answer (score 0):

Just Look for Push notification.